# How to draw this logo in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please help me draw this logo. Thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q9f0.png]

Comment: *Xin chào!* Could you please (1) add a minimal working example and showing where you are stuck and (2) add a clearer image?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @user181541: I know you are new contributor, but you should create your own logo, not by mimicking others

Answer (score 5):

It is not very difficult to draw something along these lines. However, you will be much more satisfied if you try out yourself. Then you can also add the correct/desired text, which I can't.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{2.4}
 \fill[blue!30] (-4,0) rectangle (4,4);
 \fill[blue!80!black] (-4,0) rectangle (4,-4);
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{45}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \fill[green!40!black] (1,-1,-1) -- (-1,-1,-1) -- (-1,-1,1) -- (-1,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,-1)
  -- cycle;
 \end{scope} 
 \shade[ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle[radius=0.5cm];
 \foreach \X in {0,...,15}
 {\shade[ball color=gray!30] ({360*\X/16}:0.7) circle[radius=0.05cm];}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,line join=round]
  \draw[yellow,line width=2pt]  (1,-1,-1) -- (1,-1,1) -- (-1,-1,1) -- (-1,-1,-1) 
   -- (1,-1,-1) -- (1,1,-1) -- (1,1,1)  -- (1,-1,1)
  (-1,-1,1) -- (-1,1,1) -- (1,1,1);
 \end{scope}
 \path[decoration={text along path,text color=white,
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge\sffamily\bfseries|Something},
                text align = center,
            },
            decorate
        ] (180:\radius) arc(180:0:\radius);
 \path[decoration={text along path,text color=blue!30,
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge\sffamily\bfseries|123-456-789},
                text align = center,
            },
            decorate
        ] (180:\radius) arc(180:360:\radius);
 \foreach \X in {-10,190}
 {\node[shape=star, star points=5, star point ratio=1.65, 
 inner sep=0.1cm,fill=blue!30] at (\X:\radius){};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this is too much to ask then don't bother, but if possible, could you add a few lines of comments to your tikz code? I'm in the process of learning tikz, and things like this help a lot.

Comment: @johnymm I am wondering what you like to be explained. The stuff in the scopes `\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords` uses the `tikz-3dplot` package. All the rest is beautifully explained in the `pgfmanual`. So, for instance, if you have trouble understanding what `text along path` does, search for "text along path" (if you use quotes you can search for expressions containing spaces with most viewers) and you will find several examples. If you then still have trouble with specific commands/pieces, I will be happy to answer questions (to the extent I can) after some amount of hibernation. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, I will search through the manual. I'm always a bit reticent to go through the manual simply because it's a 600+ page mammoth, but I suppose the string search makes it easier.

Comment: @johnymm As I said, if you have concrete questions, I will be happy to answer them. My main problem is that I really do not know what I am supposed to explain.

Comment: Probably nothing I can't  find in the manual. I was just hoping for an explanation of the "non-obvious" commands (it's a semi-common practice here on tex.sx). Commands like `\draw` and `\fill` are obvious in what they do, but I have no idea what the `decorations.text` library is supposed to do, or  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{2.4}`, or `\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{45}`, etc.  Again not a big deal, but that was what I meant.

Comment: @johnymm `decorations.text ` allows you to typeset text along a path, this is how the bent texts "Something" and "123-456-789" are produced. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{2.4}` only assigns a value to a macro `\radius`, that is used at several places. `\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{45}` requires `tikz-3dplot` and sets the viewing of an orthornormal projection. To see what that means, try e.g. `\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{45}`. (Notice that I only drew the visible lines, you can only adjust the viewing angles in certain ranges in this example.)